# Installer gives 2732 error :Directory Manager not initialized

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have an msi installer which was working fine. I added an external merge module. There were some directory merge errors during compilation. I removed the directories causing the error from the directory table of the merge module.

I am getting the error:

> MSI error 2732 error :Directory Manager not initialized.

Please help in solving the issue.

Answer (score 6):

The [Windows Installer Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(VS.85).aspx) documentation for error 2732 says:

"The directory manager is responsible for determining the target and source paths. It is initialized during the costing actions (CostInitialize action, FileCost action, and CostFinalize action). A standard action or custom action made a call to a function requiring the directory manager before the initialization of the directory manager. This action should be sequenced after the costing actions."

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you may not have put a backslash (\) after a directory path in the set directory action
or 
the custom action should be CostInitialize

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Dimmick said,
get the sequence number of CostIntialize from the "InstallUISequence" table.
Now go to the InstallExecuteSequence table and find your custom action and update the sequence value to the CostIntialize value.

It worked fine for me. You have to check for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible place to look at is the installation log.
Try installing the package using logging:

```
msiexec /i <package.msi> /l*v <logfile>
```

Inspecting the log looking for the line containing "**Return value 3.**". The failed custom action will show right above.